# Statically cast class this pointer to a constant pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class inheriting a stl vector and I need two functions returning the cast to vector, one mutable and another one immutable.

```
class My : public vector<int> {
  public:

    vector<int>& array() {return *static_cast<vector<int>*>(this);}
    const vector<int>& array() const {return *static_cast<vector<int>*>(this);}
}
```

Why it fails to compile for the second `const` overload?

Comment: Because you are not returning a `const vector<int>&` from the second one.

Comment: `static_cast` is attempting to remove the const-ness of the `this` pointer and returns something of type `vector<int>&`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) for more information.

Comment: FYI, `const_cast` is what you wanted, rather than `static_cast`.

Comment: @JamesRoot `this` already has the correct `const`-ness. The problem is that OP tried to use `static_cast` to remove const-ness; but the solution is to stop trying to remove const-ness (because the function returns a const reference). So `const_cast` would not be appropriate.

Comment: @M.M I meant that for removing `const`-ness, you'd need `const_cast`. It doesn't make any sense to try to do that here, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast attempts to remove the `const`-ness, which doesn't work.

However, you should just be able to write

```
vector<int>& array() {return *this;}
const vector<int>& array() const {return *this;}
```